# Where did all the questions go?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

Did the user delete [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7170/how-to-do-a-simple-set-operation-in-google-docs-spreadsheet) himself?  It seemed to be fine for this site.

**EDIT:  It looks like all the questions are gone.  You can't get past the homepage.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a temporary problem for any URL that has `/questions/` in it which causes a 404 error to show instead. I'll try to find out what's going on.

Update: it's been fixed

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now.